# Why can't I publish this click once application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a click once application which I have published to the internet. This has worked for over a year now, but after cleaning the solution I am unable to publish the application.

The only error I get is

```
Could not find file 'bin\Debug\ClutchBowlingControlPanel.exe'.
```

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3858,5): error MSB3113: Could not find file 'bin\Debug\ClutchBowlingControlPanel.exe'.
```

When I go into the Project Settings > Security and disable "Enable ClickOnce security settings" I am able to build it, but when trying to publish it, it automatically re-enables this option and does not build.

Why is it looking in bin\Debug\Application.exe when trying to build it. It does create a .exe in bin\Debug\app.publish\ but that doesn't run

On a different machine I am able to build and run it just fine, I've tried deleting the project and redownloading it from Microsoft Team Foundation, but I get the same issue. On the other machine even though I am able to build and publish it, I cannot install it as it says the application has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [10/2/2020 1:26:44 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (HashValidation)
        - File, ClutchBowlingControlPanel.pdb, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, Hash hash)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, HashCollection hashCollection)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyComponents()
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Why am I able to publish it from one machine but not another, I pulled everything from the other machine so there shouldn't be any differences.

Comment: I fixed the issue where it wouldn't build by deleting the project and downloading an old version from TFS, but It still says the hash is wrong

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can post an answer and click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer, which can help others to solve the similar issue.